# JavaFX FXML - How to show a collection in a GridPane with pagination?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have the following GridPane in FXML:

(This code was generated by JavaFX Scene Builder)

```
<GridPane fx:id="gridUsers" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="161.0" prefWidth="763.0">
  <children>
    <Label fx:id="codigoUsuarioLabel" text="Code" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
      <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" fx:id="x2" />
      </font>
    </Label>
    <Label fx:id="userNameLabel" font="$x2" text="Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
    <Label fx:id="loginUserLabel" font="$x2" text="Login" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
    <Label fx:id="userOptionsLabel" font="$x2" text="Options" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
  </children>
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="308.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="102.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="482.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="318.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="244.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="244.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="30.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="30.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

In my UserController, I have a collection with the User objects. I want to pass this collection from the Controller to the GridPane and list the objects, preferably with pagination.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [JavaFX 2.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)+, this version of JavaFX has a built-in Pagination control which can provide.  Otherwise you will need to write such a functionality yourself or backport the control from the [2.2 open source repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt) into your code.